# Has_many through form

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am hoping for some help with constructing a form a has_many :through relationship.

I have three classes:

**order.rb**

```
has_many :selections
has_many :items, :through =>:selections;
```

**item.rb**

```
has_many :selections
has_many :orders, :through => :selections
```

**selection.rb**

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :item
```

Selections has an extra property on it to capture the quantity of the selected item.

What I'm trying to do is create a form that allows a user check a box indicating the type of item they want and supply a quantity.

```
_X_ Food1 _6_
___ Food2 __
_X_ Food3 _1_
```

My problem is that I don't have any idea how to name the form elements so that they make it into the controller. I can't use

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:order, :item_ids, @course.items.all, :id, :name, {:item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'}) %>
```

because that will just print the food with checkboxes and I need to capture the quantity for each selected item.

What I could use help with is how to create the _form.html.erb as well as special gotcha's that I might need to have in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

First off, item.rb should read,

```
has_many :selections
has_many :orders, :through => :selections
```

Secondly, why are you using a check box? Why not just forms that if empty default to zero or nil? That is, if you have more than one, you can use it as a truthy value in lieu of a check being checked or not.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo on the item.

Your suggesting that I just do 

    Food1 [2]
    Food2 [ ]
    Food3 [4]

Thats definitely a better way but I'm still unsure how to construct the form so that the selections get correctly populated by the controller.

Comment: Can you go a little further into what you're trying to do?